# Computing single line text dimensions in JavaFX 2

Tags: string, text, size, javafx, dimensions

In order to position a custom cursor, I need to be able to compute the dimensions (width, height, and baseline) of a single-line string, given a given Font.

In Java Swing, this was (I seem to recall) done with a method call on Font, but in JavaFX 2, the only way I can discover to do this is to put the text in a Label and query the label.

This seems like an awkward way of doing things. Is there a better way?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

There's a [feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-8060) for it on the JavaFX JIRA site.  So it's not available yet, but maybe worth adding your vote.